# ¿Donde se guardan los Logs de Java? ¿Como puedo elegir donde?

Tags: java

Me imagino que debe existir una ruta por defecto donde se guardan los Logs cuando se utiliza el Logger de Java.
Mis preguntas son dos:

> 1) ¿Cual es esa ruta por defecto?
>
> 2) ¿Como hago para especificar una diferente?

No estoy usando ninguna librería externa (log4j), solo Java 1.8.

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) La ruta por defecto la puedes encontrar definida en el archivo logging.properties que se encuentra en el directorio \jre\lib de tu instalación de Java, ejemplo:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib
```

dentro de muestra la ruta:

```
# default file output is in user's home directory.
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = %h/java%u.log
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2) Para guardar el log en una ruta especifica puedes usar este script que usa la clase [**Logger**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html) en el cual definirás el nombre y la ruta donde se guardaría el Log:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("LogdeNacho");      
String pathLog = "C:/Datos/MyLog.log";
try {      

    FileHandler fhandler = new FileHandler(pathLog);  
    logger.addHandler(fhandler);
    SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();  
    fhandler.setFormatter(formatter);  

} catch (SecurityException e){  
    e.printStackTrace();  
} catch (IOException e){  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

posteriormente puedes agregar a tu archivo .log los mensajes mediante `logger.info()` por ejemplo:

```
   logger.info("Probando el código!");
   try {            
        String a = "SO";
        int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        logger.info("ocurrió un error en el código!");
        logger.info("NumberFormatException " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    logger.info("terminé...");
```

En tu archivo log,  se guardaría esta información:

```
ago 10, 2021 8:24:27 PM copydirectories.MainClass main
INFO: Probando el código!
ago 10, 2021 8:24:27 PM copydirectories.MainClass main
INFO: ocurrió un error en el código!
ago 10, 2021 8:24:27 PM copydirectories.MainClass main
INFO: NumberFormatException For input string: "SO"
ago 10, 2021 8:24:27 PM copydirectories.MainClass main
INFO: terminé...
```